# Is there any stock exchange that doesn't use ticker symbols (a.k.a. stock symbols)?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

I read on [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/129714/5656) by [kurtosis](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/101544/kurtosis):

> Stock tickers exist on most stock exchanges and are unique to an exchange or country.

Is there any stock exchange that doesn't use [ticker symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol) (a.k.a. stock symbols)?

Comment: If a stock exchange doesn't use ticker symbols, ticker symbols will still be given by third-parties anyway (e.g. Bloomberg symbols, Reuters RIC).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any such exchanges.

However, exchanges mostly trade common stock and ETFs (see this excellent overview: https://stockmarketmba.com/abouttheusstockmarket.php).

Whereas ISIN identifies any kind of security, eg bonds, debt instruments, secondary instruments, etc. So there are many ISIN that are not associated with a ticker.

AFAIK there are over 80M ISIN in the world, but only about 75k publicly traded companies. Which makes maybe 100-150k tickers because many common shares are traded on multiple exchanges. See eg this answer https://money.stackexchange.com/a/156606/122732, or one of these pages and try the drop-down next to the ticker name:

- https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/summary?s=TSLA:VIE
- https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/summary?s=META:NSQ