# Given one ISIN, how can I get the list of all the stock exchanges on which it is traded, along with its ticker symbols if any?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, isin

Given one International Securities Identification Number (ISIN), how can I get the list of all the stock exchanges on which it is traded, along with its ticker symbols [if any](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/129720/5656)?

Answer (score 18):

This is trickier than it might seem. There are a few issues: access, data completeness, and cross-listings vs depository receipts.

**Access**

The first difficulty is access to this information. You can try searching at various websites or via Google; however, some of the information is... well, not right. Your best bet is buying data from a company like Refinitiv or using a Bloomberg. Obviously, these both cost money.

**Data Completeness**

Suppose you have access to a Bloomberg. You could enter an ISIN or a Bloomberg code (usually a ticker or something close) plus the exchange or country code as arguments to `RELS` (related securities). You can also do this lookup with an ISIN by first finding the security with `ID US0123456789` (if that were the ISIN).

An illuminating example that should be easy is Sony (6758 on the Tokyo Stock Exchange). So you could enter `6758 JP Equity RELS` and get related securities to Sony's TSE listing: some equities, some bonds, and some convertible bonds and warrants historically. In my experience, however, Bloomberg sometimes does not list all the relevant related securities.

You might think it is easy to go the the company's website. If you go to Sony's site and wander around, you will eventually find investor relations. There, they list Sony stock as 6758 on the Tokyo Stock Exchange and SNE on the New York Stock Exchange. However, if you search the web you will find Sony trading on Deutsche Börse, the Vienna Stock Exchange, on the London Stock Exchange, and elsewhere. Sony might trade on other exchanges as well; those are just the exchanges with pages about the stocks they trade.

**Cross-Listings vs Depository Receipts**

Another issue is that many stocks "listed" on international exchanges are not actually listed there; instead, depository receipts are listed. American or Global depository receipts (ADRs/GDRs) are essentially delta-1 derivatives: they hold 1 (or sometimes another amount) of shares in a depository receipt and pass-through dividends, capital gains, splits, etc.

Let's go back to Sony. The ISIN for Sony on the Tokyo Stock Exchange (6758) is JP3435000009. However, the ISIN for Sony on the New York Stock Exchange (SNE) is US8356993076. SNE is an ADR, something not mentioned on Sony's website. A little more searching suggests that all of the other international listings are for the US ISIN -- the ADR.

The issue with this is searching with one ISIN may not uncover the other ISIN(s).

Are there firms with true cross-listings? Yes, I recall IBM had cross-listed their shares on the Deutsche Börse; however, there was not a lot of volume in the cross-listed shares. The expense of cross-listing was unlikely to be worthwhile.

**Conclusion**

So, can you find all places where a company's stock trades? Perhaps, but it will not be easy. If you care about depository receipts, it is likely to be harder.

Comment: There is at least one "true" cross-listed stock on the TSX and NYSE: BMO. See https://www.bmo.com/home/about/banking/investor-relations/shareholder-information . Interestingly BMO can be used to do currency exchange by buying on one exchange and selling on the other, or so I've been told. I suspect that true cross-listings may be common between Canada and the US given our geographic and economic situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the ticker symbols and exchanges worldwide associated with a stock or fixed-income instrument by looking up the security's ISIN on [Stock Market MBA](https://stockmarketmba.com/lookupisinonopenfigi.php). It is not only free (at least for now) but also has extensive coverage based on the data from [OpenFIGI](https://www.openfigi.com) whose supporters include Bloomberg.

Answer (score 0):

The Financial Times has that information in a drop-down list under the name.

Try e.g. https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/summary?s=K:NYQ